# верстка блока с 3-мя карточками

Tags: html, css

дико прошу помощи :) 
Ситуация такая, есть блок:
[image]
Они должны находится в центре своего блока и картинки как бы тоже должны быть по центру относительно своего блока (**чё он несет?**), в общем говоря, у меня так не получается сделать, т.к опыта недостаточно, надеюсь на вашу помощь..)

Вот что вышло у меня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код:

```
<div class="block_cards">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="images/device.png" alt="">
                <p>Optimized for all devices</p>
                <p>STRICT has been designed to be fully 
                responsive on all devices</p>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <img src="images/device.png" alt="">
                <p>Optimized for all devices</p>
                <p>STRICT has been designed to be fully 
                responsive on all devices</p>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <img src="images/device.png" alt="">
                <p>Optimized for all devices</p>
                <p>STRICT has been designed to be fully 
                responsive on all devices</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.block_cards
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 66px;

}

.block_cards img
{

}

.block_cards .card p
{
    width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такие изменения в CSS:

```
.block_cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 66px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 250px;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.card__descriptor {
  text-align: center;
}
```

В HTML для тега P с описанием добавить класс "card__descriptor"
Пример собрал https://codepen.io/ilya-lokalin/pen/qBBQEKW